# Window Leak issue when triggering an AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog.Builder` that fires off when a user first opens the app if they do not have a network connection. The `AlertDialogh` as a `NeutralButton` that once clicked jumps into a `startActivity`.

I get a `leaked window` error. Not sure how to fix this issue since I am not able to `.dismiss()` or `.cancel()` the `AlertDialog`.

Is there another way to go about displaying this alert?

This is inside `onCreate`

```
        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        checkVersion();
    }else{
         AlertDialog.Builder warning = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         warning.setCancelable(false);
         warning.setTitle("Network Connection Not Established");
         warning.setMessage("Data will not be Synchronized. To have data Synchronized close the application and connect to WiFi or Cell Sevice Provider then Reopen.");
         warning.setNeutralButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            findView();
                        }
                    });
         warning.show();
    }
```

The `checkVersion()` works no issues it is the `findView()` that gives the error

```
    private void findView(){
    locationId = datasource.selectSettingsLocation();
    if(locationId != 0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Startup.this, Return.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Startup.this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

The else is what is being triggered in this case `Intent intent = new Intent(Startup.this, Main.class);`

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get a leaked window error

You didn't posted relevant code but you need to call `dismiss()` on your Dialog before you're going to next Activity - in that time Context of current Activity is going to **null** and this is reason why you're getting this kind of Exception.

So in your case, you can do it like:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder warning = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
...
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
   warning.dismiss();
   findView();
}
```

Just you need to make your Dialog as final field to be able to use it in method of anonymous class.

Comment: I was trying `warning.dismiss()`, did not realize I was able to reference `AlertDialog` with `Dialog`

Comment: @N0M3 ;) now you know and will know in future ;) good luck in programming - sometimes it's very funny and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the "wrong" context. Please paste your code. If you use your code in a fragment use `AlterDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`

Else please post your coding.

Comment: You're guessing or you know it?

Comment: I know that he would get this error, if he uses the DialogBuilder within a fragment with `new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())`, but because I don't know his coding, I just can guess, what's wrong ;)

Comment: He is guessing because there is no code to look at.